# When does VIM reevaluate foldexpr?

Tags: vim

I am trying to figure out when VIM's `foldexpr` is reevaluated.

In my case, I have `set foldexpr=MySpecialFunction(v:lnum)` and it seems to me that `MySpecialFunction` is only called when the buffer is opened or when I delete a line that closes a fold.

Intuitively, I would have assumed that I can trigger a reevaluation with `ctrl-l` yet it doesn't.

For what it is worth: my VIM's version is 7.3

Comment: You can use `zx` and `zX` to force the folds to be refreshed, although those commands also have the side effect of possibly opening/closing manually opened/closed folds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is no way documented to force reevaluating the foldexpr. I have asked the same some time ago at the vim mailinglist. In the end, a patch was made, that made zx and zX reevaluate the foldexpression, which was good enough for me.

I only noticed two ways to force to reevaluate the foldexpression: to have a noop filter (e.g. filter through cat) or reset the foldexpression.

See the discussion in the vim mailinglist:
http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/msg/6f13fa0dfcb06317